# Kivy - Bind Label Text To Variable (Python Only)

Tags: python, properties, label, kivy

I have been trying to get my labels to auto-update themselves for quite a while now and I have read over a dozen StackOverflow questions but to no avail.

I have an global object that contains an integer value that I want to be displayed with a label inside of one of my widget classes.

The widget class looks like this:

```
class Battle(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Battle, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #Enemy Stats
        self.enemyBar = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size=(Window.width, Window.height/8), center_y = Window.height - self.height/2)
        self.enemyBar.add_widget(Label(text=enemy.name))

        #Enemy Health Label
        health_label = Label(text=str(enemy.health))
        self.enemyBar.add_widget(health_label)
        self.add_widget(self.enemyBar)


    def update_health(instance, value):
        health_label.text = str(enemy.health) #<-- Error happens here

    enemy.bind(health=update_health)
```

When the value of `enemy.health` is changed in the program, I want my label to change as well. I do not want to use any of the kivy language because I prefer having just one main python file.

The enemy object is created with an entity class. Here is the entity code:

```
class entity(Widget):
    #entity creation
    health = NumericProperty() 

    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health
```

When I run the code I press a button that calls a function that changes the enemy health and then I get an error:

*global name 'health_label' is not defined*

Somehow, when the update_health function is called, the program doesn't see the health_label variable that was created in the init.

Comment: I got a fix by making the health_label variable a global one, right now that is the only way I can get the results I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the bind method, something like the following

```
health_label = Label(text=enemy.health)
self.enemyBar.add_widget(health_label)
def update_health(instance, value):
    health_label.text = str(enemy.health)
enemy.bind(health=update_health)
```

This is just a basic example off the top of my head, it can be made neater depending on the structure of your program. If enemy.health is a string, you can just do `enemy.bind(health=health_label.setter('text'))`.

For this to work, the health attribute must be a kivy property:

```
class Enemy(Something):
    health = StringProperty('')
```

In your code it seems that enemy is a global object. There is quite likely a better way to do that. Also, I recommend using kv language - there is not really any special value in putting your code in one file (indeed, it's commonly considered bad practice once it gets non-trivial), and kv makes a lot of things easier where python just isn't suited to certain tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still having trouble implementing this code. I have updated my question to give you more information about how I created the enemy object and declare the health variable. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I made the `health_label` in the init a global variable, and it works. I'm sure there is a better way to define the variable, but right now I have a solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To add to what inclement said, you can add various types of bindings to the elements you make. Just keep in mind that there's a different way to do it for the elements generating an action, such as a button. Here is an example of what I used to create a button to search for nearby Bluetooth devices (but the only thing you have to think about are the methods I use) :

```
    size = dp(50)
    b = Button(text="Start Research", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1,size))
    self.bind(searching_devices=b.setter("disabled"))
    b.bind(on_press=self.start_searching)
    self.add_widget(b)
```

Here **searching_devices** is a BooleanProperty and **start_searching()** is a function.
As you can see, the *disabled* property, which 'gives' an information to the button is binded with a setter, just as the text element inclement talked about. For an action which is generated by using the component like the *on_press* property, you bind it directly without the setter.