# Kivy: EventDispatcher updated value to Label in Python

Tags: python, kivy

I was hoping someone might be able to help me on one part of my Kivy/Python script I am hung up on. I am sure there is a quick solution to an experienced Kivy user. I have looked into other posts ([Kivy Update Dynamic Label Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877241/kivy-update-dynamic-label-text)) but did not work for me, I am thinking because they are with older versions of Kivy (v1.7 and I am using v1.10).

I have a regularly scheduled function callback for my_fun as may be seen in the code. The details of the for loop are irrelevant, but inside the my_fun function, ins.a takes on the third index value of my_Array, calling on the 'on_a' function as normal when the value is updated. Now, I need the label 'labelA1var' text to update with this value (instead of x1, currently just there as a place holder)

Thank you in advance!

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import vertex_instructions
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import RoundedRectangle, Line
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher

Config.exit_on_escape = 1


class MainClass(FloatLayout):

    layout = FloatLayout(size=Window.size,pos=Window.center)
    x1 = 100                              #Position all widgets using values 
    y1 = 100

    #Define Labels (left just one label for my example)

    labelA1var = Label(text='%d V' %(x1),color = (0,0,0,1),font_size = 20, pos = (-250 +x1, -26 +y1))

    #Add Labels to Screen
    layout.add_widget(labelA1var)

    Window.add_widget(layout)

    def my_fun(dt):
        x = 0
        global my_Array
        my_Array = []
        print("My Function Running")
        read = [0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
        reading = read + read + read + read                         #256 bytes read ==> 64 32 bit values
        for i in range(0,64):
            data32 = (reading[x] << 24) | (reading[x+1] << 16) | (reading[x+2] << 8) | reading[x+3]
            my_Array.append(data32)
            #print('The current uint32 value is: %d' % data32)
            x += 4
            if x >= 252:
                x = 0
                print('x reset to zero')
        print('my_Array Length is: %s' %len(my_Array))
        ins.a = my_Array[2]
        print(ins.a)
        return my_Array

#Scheduled Fucntion Callbacks
v = 1
#Call on my_fun with frequency v
my_event = Clock.schedule_interval(my_fun,v)          

class Events(EventDispatcher):
    a = NumericProperty(0)
    def on_a(self, instance, value):
        print('a updated')


ins = Events()

class KivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Change Title"             #Set Window Title
        Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
        Window.clearcolor = (0.25,0.25,0.25,0.7)            
        return MainClass()

    def on_stop(self):
        print('Window Closed')


window = KivyApp()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.run()
```

Comment: Can you just call `MainClass.labelA1var.text = str(value)` in your `on_a()` method?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, was just missing the MainClass. Before the rest of it